# TypeScript naming convention for packages/namespace plural or singular?

Tags: namespaces, typescript, naming-conventions, package

What is the naming convention for TypeScript `package/namespace` names, plural or singular? I couldn't find any reference so far.

Example:

```
Application.Models
```

or

```
Application.Model
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its purely subjective.

I would name it `Application.Models` if it has `Model`s.

Comment: Okay, so there aren't any official naming convention about it? Thanks.

Comment: Nope. None from the TS team.